# Query Multiple Taxominies Across Multiple Post type's

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tax-query

i have searched and found some aprroved answers to similer questions
but nothing i could make work or something exactly like my issue...

**i have 5 custom post type...**
each one have its own taxmonies and inside all of them i have created
a category called specials... i need to pull all posts marked with 
this category from all post types...

**i have currently stuck starring at this code which doesent work..**

```
$itemsAmount = of_get_option('sg_specials_amount');

query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => array('engagement_ring', 'wedding_ring', 'pendants', 'earrings', 'bracelets'),
    'posts_per_page' => $itemsAmount,                       
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'wedding_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'specials'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'engagement_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'specials'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')                       
) );
```

*(in this example code trying to pull just from two taxomonies but would use five)*
.

if relevant then beneath the code i pasted here i have
the loop which can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ds4kFptq

Would appreciate your help
Sagive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, I would guess that the problem is your use of

```
'relation' => 'AND'
```

Using `AND` means that you will only return items that fall into *all* of the taxonomy terms. If you want to return items have *any* of the taxonomy items, change it to

```
'relation' => 'OR'
```

If that "doesn't work", please provide more details about what "it doesn't work" means :)